# How to use global extern and call in assembly

Tags: assembly, bootloader

Implementing global and extern instructions in assembly seem not to work

I'm currently creating a bootloader in assembly, but calling or jumping into a label from another file brought no errors, but having wrong output

Making use of `%include <path/to/directory>` works fine, but I also need to make use of the call instruction too

Here's what I tried:

I had to reduce the code to minimal

#start.asm

```
[bits 16]
global _start
extern printc

_start:
    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov al, "H"
    call printc

    jmp $

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0

dw 0xaa55
```

#print.asm:

```
[bits 16]

global printc

printc:
    int 0x10
    ret
```

I compile it using:

nasm -f elf64 start.asm -o start.o
nasm -f elf64 print.asm -o print.o

ld -s -Ttext=0x7c00 start.o print.o -o printer.elf

objcopy -O binary printer.elf printer.bin

and I used the qemu emulator
qemu-system-x86_64 -drive format=raw,file=printer.bin

And the output is:

```
Booting from Hard Disk...
_
```

what am I not getting right?

Comment: That's too minimal, you didn't show any build commands for how you were trying to assemble and link this.  Also, use `code blocks` (triple backticks), and don't double-space your code.  A separate code block for each file is good.

Comment: `times 510 - ($-$$) db 0` / `dw 0xaa55` is handled at assemble-time for that one file.  Linking it with something else will put the .text section of from the other `.asm` after the 512 bytes from the first file, where it won't get loaded by the BIOS.  Look at the size of your `.bin` file, and check a hexdump or use `ndisasm -b16` to see where your code is.  If you want to use the linker this way, you need a linker script to generate the `0xaa55` signature at the end, as in [What exactly does ". = 0x7c00" in a linker script do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43348913)

Comment: [Role of linker scripts when writing x86 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59700854) has another detailed example.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that the codes from the second file is placed after the magic number (0xaa55) after using hd and xxd, but I couldn't understand how to make it right. Now I know where to look, rather than thinking about something else that isn't the problem. I'll check the links you provided. Thanks @PeterCordes

Comment: [Calculating padding length with GAS AT&T directives for a boot sector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47859273) mentions the case of multiple `.o` files, and shows a usable linker script for linking them, and having the linker add the signature.  Not a duplicate, though, since it's primarily about using GAS instead of NASM.  The fact that no assembler directive can work when you're linking multiple object files (instead of using `%include` of source files) is kind of a bonus part of Michael Petch's excellent answer.  (Definitely check out his other answers, like his general bootloader tips)

Comment: For a bootloader you should ask NASM to use the BIN format. Instead of `nasm -f elf64 start.asm` write `nasm -f bin start.asm`.

Comment: using the `nasm -f bin <file>` format is not possible with `extern` instruction

Comment: I've tried a hell of things and could not still resolve it
Here's my current progress for the start.asm file

```assembly
[bits 16]
global _start
extern print
_start:
    xor ax,ax
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax
    mov bx,0x8000
    cli
    mov ss,bx
    mov sp,ax
    sti
    cld

    mov ah, 0x0e
    mov al, "H"

    call print
    jmp $

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55

Comment: I guess I'll have to stick with the %include directive, but please I hope it won't affect later, especially in the case of loading the kernel